# How to add SSL certificate from AWS to .NET 2.1

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to add an SSL certificate to my .NET code. I have the certificate on AWS and it is connected to my Elastic Beanstalk environment (via EC2) that is running the application but I'm trying to connect to a [PlanetScale Dataabse](https://planetscale.com/) but it's unable to connect as the application does not have access to the CA certificate on the EC2 instance.

How would I give the application access to the certificate that is on the EC2 instance or how would I put that certificate in the code for the application to use?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your AWS certificate is a free certificate you created in AWS ACM, then that is attached to the load balancer, and will not be available from your EC2 instance.

The SSL certificates you need to use to connect to PlanetScale are completely separate, and completely unrelated to your web site SSL certificate.

What you need is the root certificate to verify PlanetScale's SSL certificate. The [PlanetScale documentation](https://docs.planetscale.com/reference/secure-connections#mysql-command-line-client) indicates their root certificate should already be on your server because they use a public certificate authority. Did you check the `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` and `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` paths they tell you to check on your server?

Comment: No, I'm not sure how to find them, what should I search for?

Comment: I literally gave you the filenames to look for.

Comment: oh sorry, I did check my code and they don't exist, I guess that's why it doesn't work. How do I get them?

Comment: Those files would be on your server, not in your code. They would be part of the Linux distribution.